# Class not persistence?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I'm trying to store in the GAE DB a class which some of its fields are classes themselves.
Just before going into more details I want to say it worked just fine before I added these new class field.
So, I followed the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses
and I'm getting this error :

> org.datanucleus.jdo.exceptions.ClassNotPersistenceCapableException: The class "The class "sporteam.web.client.User" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found." is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data for the class is not found.

The main class I'm trying to use is User:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class User implements Serializable 
{
    // data members

    // user unique facebook id
    @Persistent
    @PrimaryKey
    private String facebook_id;

    // users facebook code
    @Persistent
    private String facebook_code;

    // users device ID code
    @Persistent
    private String dev_id;

    // users registration ID code
    @Persistent
    private String reg_id;

    // user first name
    @Persistent
    private String first_name;

    // user last name
    @Persistent
    private String last_name;

    // user age, should be grater then 8
    @Persistent
    private int age;

    // user email, as setup in facebook
    @Persistent
    private String email;

    // user weight, should be greater then 40
    @Persistent
    private double weight;

    // user workout_level (0.8 is the highest(best shape) and 1 is the lowest)
    @Persistent
    private double workout_level;

    // user gender ("male"/"female"/"unknown")
    @Persistent
    private String gender;
    @Persistent
    @Embedded
    private UserTracks userTracks = null;

    // default constructor
    public User() 
    {
    }
    //....
}
```

This is the UserTracks class:

```
    @PersistenceCapable
    @EmbeddedOnly
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class UserTracks implements Serializable 
    {
        @Persistent
        @Embedded
        //@Element(embedded="true") 
        private List<Track> tracks = null;
        @Persistent
        private long date = 0;

        public UserTracks() 
        {
        }
    }
```

And theses are the other 2 classes used:

```
    @PersistenceCapable
    @EmbeddedOnly
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class Track implements Serializable 
    {

        /** running information **/
        @Persistent
        private double avgSpeed = 0;
        @Persistent
        private double distance = 0;
        @Persistent
        private double calories = 0;
        @Persistent
        private long time = 0;

        /************************/
        @Persistent
        private long date = 0;
        @Persistent
        private String name = null;
        @Persistent
        @Embedded
        private List<GeoPtr> track = null;

        public Track() 
        { // needed for Serializable
        }
    }
```

GeoPtr:

```
    @PersistenceCapable
    @EmbeddedOnly
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class GeoPtr implements Serializable 
    {

        /** the speed is in m/s **/
        @Persistent
        float speed;
        @Persistent
        long time;
        @Persistent
        double altitude;
        @Persistent
        double latitude;
        @Persistent
        double longitude;
        @Persistent
        double calorie = 0;

        public GeoPtr()
        {   //needed for Serializable
        }
    }
```

As far as I can see, every class is PersistenceCapable and all the fields are either PersistenceCapable themselves or a collection of it and according to the documentation above it should work.

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: "This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found." So which one of those applies ... because one certainly does. You can easily check what is in the CLASSPATH, and whether enhanced (javap tells you what methods a class has)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to use embedded class Track to store collection of GeoPtr to UserTracks. How DataStore will handle it? When embedding into UserTracks fields of GeoPtr added to common single record in DataStore. You will have:

avgSpeed, distance, ...., speed, time

What DataStore should do in collection case?

avgSpeed, distance, ...., speed_1, time_1, ..., speed_2, time_2, ... speed_N, time_N

???

Is this make any sence?

Don't use embedded. Create three separate classes with primary keys. Use one-to-one relationship for User - UserTracks and one-to-many for UserTracks - GeoPtr.
Read about relations [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships)

Comment: It is possible to embed a collection field. I wanted this field embedded and not in a different tables. I didnt want it so I can see them in the datastore viewer, it can hold it like a regular object for all I care.Thanks anyways :)

Comment: You can make it serializable and write to blob field. But there can be other issue: size is limit with 1MB. If your collection will be too large - you'll get an exception

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently there is some problem with embedding a collection of user defined classes.
I've read somewhere that its not possible to embed a collection field that has an embedded collection field itself. However, you can achieve almost the same by serializing these fields (you wont be able to index them - that's the difference between serialized to embedded, but I don't need indexes on these fields for my use so it worked out just fine) you can do so by using the next notation :
@Persistent(serialized = "true")

Hoped it will save all of you the pain I've been through.

Bar.